# Vectorized ifelse statements for bucketization

Tags: r

I have written a function that accepts a vector of hours-of-the-day, i.e. numbers between 0 and 23, and places each hour into one of 8 contiguous buckets. For example, hours 0, 1, and 2 are placed into bucket 1, and hours 21, 22, and 23 are in bucket 8. The buckets are returned as a vector.

The ifelse structure is really complex, and in the future I may increase or decrease the size of each bucket. Can someone suggest an alternative?

```
getBucket <- function(hour)
{
    ifelse (hour < 3, 1, ifelse (hour < 6, 2, ifelse (hour < 9, 3, ifelse (hour < 12, 4, ifelse (hour < 15, 5, ifelse (hour < 18, 6, ifelse (hour < 21, 7, 8)))))))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple with integer division:

```
hours <- 0:23

hours %/% 3 + 1
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of this. I actually tried hours %% 8 earlier.

Answer (score 3):

```
 hours <- c(23,11,2,5, 0)
 findInterval(hours, seq(0, 23, by=3) )
 [1] 8 4 1 2 1
```